# store private api key in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am using firebase and my backend API to get data for my APP.

The api requires a  GCP key from access. This key expires every 90 days. So, I cannot store the key in the client/phone.

Need some ideas of where can I store the key.. I tried Firebase remote config and it works but the Firebase documentation said that sensitive data should not be used .

Creating a backend service that return the keys will not be secure as anyone can call the service,,

Need some suggestion. Is Firestore/Realtime database an option. The app will only read the data. However when the data changes(new keys) the App should get the latest.

Thanks for any suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While distributing a private API key to the app at runtime through a mechanism like Remote Config, or a cloud database, may reduce the risk of it being intercepted, it is not enough to deter a sufficiently motivated malicious user. That's why the Remote Config documentation recommends against it, and the same applies to other distribution mechanisms (such as the databases you mention).

If this is a private API key, you should not use it in client-side code, period. That's really the only solution. When you use it in client-side code, a malicious user may get access to it and then abuse the backend service that is protected by the private API key.

Private API keys should be kept private, and only be used in a trusted environment (such as your development machine, a server you control, or Cloud Functions). When you allow users of your app to make calls through that private environment (by defining your own API for them), you will have to secure that end point yourself to ensure only authorized users can access them.

Comment: Thanks but my mobile app need to communicate with the API on the server. To do this is needs a key. This key changes ever 90 days. How can  the client talk to API.. I need the key and I have to store it somewhere.. what do you recommend?

Comment: I recommend keeping the private key on a trusted environment only, exposing the necessary functionality in a custom API, and securing access to that API to fit your needs.